# AIR/Flex .NET remoting without webserver

Tags: .net, apache-flex, air, weborb, fluorinefx

I have an AIR application that connects to a local .NET backend through a socket. On the backend side (written in C#), the TcpListener class is used to handle incoming messages and send responses back to the client. Currently we use XML to format the requests, but this requires quite some manual work and extra code to (de)serialize the messages.

Using RemoteObject, we would not need to do any of that (de)serialization ourselves and would be able to execute remote calls in which the objects we send would be automatically mapped. We can't use this though since we are not running a webserver and can hence not set up a remoting gateway.

Does anyone have any advice on how we could do this? Is there anything available in FluorineFX or WebORB to achieve this, or would this require us to create a custom handler?

Comment: Isn't there something like an embedded web server you can use? If you were using Java, I would recommend embedding Jetty (and use blazeds)

Comment: WebOBR has to be either deployed into your application or started as a standalone app. In any case, you have to up the web server (IIS for the .NET version or any app container for the Java version). I believe the same is true for any other solutions such as FluorineFX, BlaseDS and so on)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could easily use the FluorineFX sources to accomplish what you want. FluorineFX also installs a windows service for remote messaging. The projects can be downloaded from source control. I know there's a Windows Service project which you could look at. It also uses sockets (I think) to communicate with the web server.

I guess you could start by using the serializers/deserializers from FluorineFX to parse amf to objects and objects to amf...

http://old.nabble.com/Documentation-on-how-to-use-FluorineFx-as-Windows-Service--td15849073.html